# Calling protocol methods on super

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, protocols

Can I call a protocol method from a child on its super class, even though the super class supports the protocol privately?

Let's say I have a Class A which privately conforms to UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol. Class B inherits from Class A but when I tried to call [super gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:gestureRecognizer]; I get an error.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [UIScrollViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html) doesn't declare a method named `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:gestureRecognizer:`.

But generally speaking, yes, its possible to call methods declared in protocols that the super class implements, but keep in mind that methods marked with `@optional` in the protocol aren't guaranteed to be implemented (you can check this via the `respondsToSelector:` method)

Comment: Great Call! And what about a situation where the Class A privately conforms to the protocol? How can I tell that to the compiler?

Comment: @Rizon By casting the pointer to the object to something like: `id<MyPrivateProtocol> bar = foo;` and then you use `bar` and the compiler won't complain.

Comment: Yeah, but the ONLY problem is that 'foo' in my case is actually should be 'super'

Comment: @Rizon Ufff, I see... I fear that you are out of options in this case. You could try to forge a custom call to `objc_msgSendSuper()` via `libiffi` but I don't know if this is available on iOS... I guess its easier to suppress the compilers warning via a `#pragma push` for the invocation because if the method is implemented by A, it will receive it regardless if the compiler can see the implementation or not.

Comment: In your `UIScrollView` subclass, just declare a category with the methods, that will take care of the compiler error/warning. When calling, make sure to check the superclass still responds to those selectors (in case something changing in-between system releases).